# CollapsingToolbarLayout title disappears

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-titlebar

I have a CollapsingToolBarLayout.When the navigation drawer closes, the title on the toolbar disappears.This happens only when the Toolbar is in collapsed state. While in Expanded state the title remains.I have checked the code But i 'm unable to find the bug.
here is my code for main activity:-

```
  import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
    import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;  
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import com.defcomm.invento.NavigationDrawerActivity;
     import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

     public class INVENTO extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private CoordinatorLayout mCoordinator;
    private CollapsingToolbarLayout mCollapsableLayout;
    private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
        mCoordinator= (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
        mCollapsableLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        mCollapsableLayout.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        nestedScrollView= (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.rvToDoList);
        mCollapsableLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
        mCollapsableLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));
        NavigationDrawerActivity drawerFragment= (NavigationDrawerActivity) getSupportFragmentManager().
                findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
            drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout), toolbar);


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_invento, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
```

main activity xml file:-

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.defcomm.invento.INVENTO">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="#3f51b5"
                app:contentScrim="@color/primaryColor"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/index"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

                    android:id="@+id/appbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/rvToDoList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="5dp"

                />
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:name="com.defcomm.invento.NavigationDrawerActivity"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
     }
```

my navigation java file:-

```
 import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;  
    import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

     public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends Fragment {


    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mdrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mdrawerLayout;
    private boolean mUserLearnedState;
    private CoordinatorLayout mcoordinator;
    private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
    View containerId;
    public static final String file_pref_name = "Testpef";
    public static final String KEY_USER_VALUE = "user_learned_drawer";
    private boolean mfromSavedInstanceState;

    public NavigationDrawerActivity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedState = Boolean.valueOf(readPreference(getActivity(), KEY_USER_VALUE, "false"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mfromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        //recyclerview= (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        return layout;

    }


    public void setUp(final int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerlayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
        mdrawerLayout = drawerlayout;

        containerId = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mdrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerlayout, toolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!mUserLearnedState) {
                    mUserLearnedState = true;
                    saveToPreference(getActivity(), KEY_USER_VALUE, mUserLearnedState + "");
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                if (slideOffset < 0.5f) {
                    toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset);
                }
            }
        };
        if (!mUserLearnedState && !mfromSavedInstanceState) {
            mdrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerId);
        }

        mdrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mdrawerToggle);
        mdrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mdrawerToggle.syncState();

            }
        });

    }


    public static void saveToPreference(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
        SharedPreferences shared = context.getSharedPreferences(file_pref_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
        editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readPreference(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences share = context.getSharedPreferences(file_pref_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return share.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and found out there is an example repo that was created to demo this issue [here](https://github.com/nealsanche/DisappearingTitleDemo). If that link doesn't work, checkout my forked version [here](https://github.com/vishrayne/DisappearingTitleDemo)

After some random experiments I found out that removing  `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` (attribute) set on AppBarLayout solves this issue. Attaching [Fixed layout file](https://github.com/vishrayne/DisappearingTitleDemo/blob/fix_disappearing_title/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml)  and [MainActivity](https://github.com/vishrayne/DisappearingTitleDemo/blob/fix_disappearing_title/app/src/main/java/org/nsdev/disappearingtitle/MainActivity.java) for your reference.

And FYI, your `setup` method defined on `NavigationDrawerActivity` attempts to set title on Toolbar but as per the official guide you need to set the title on the CollapsingToolBarLayout instead of the Toolbar. 
I will suggest you to use `NavigationView`(from design support library) instead of a custom DrawerFragment unless you want to add fancy/custom behaviour to your navigation drawer.